# Google Maps API: update Marker color

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have several **Google Maps Markers colors** depending on whether conditions are **TRUE** or **not**.

Additionally these Markers **change color when mouse is over a division** (a1,a2..ax).

I'd like these Markers to go back to the **color set previously** when mouse leaves the division.

Would it give something like : 'save Marker state color' before **marker.setIcon** and then caling back this color on **mouseleave**?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my code, working fine except that every marker is blue after **mouseleave**.

```
function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?= json_encode($lat); ?>, <?= json_encode($lng);?>),
    zoom: <?php echo json_encode($zoom); ?>,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl(<?= json_encode($url); ?>, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var cf = markers[i].getAttribute("cf");
      var wh = markers[i].getAttribute("wh");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var image1 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
      var image2 = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';



      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point    

      });

      if (cf == "true") 
      {
          marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');
      }


      else if (wh == "true") 
      {
          marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png');
      }

     else
     {
         marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png');
     }

       hover(marker,i);
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);      
    }
    });
  }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });
}

function hover(marker, i){
document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseover = function() {
   marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png');
}
document.getElementById('a'+i).onmouseleave = function() {
   marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png');
}
    }

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };


  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (it probably doesn't depend on the XML file that the posted code requires).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use function closure in a createMarker function to associate the event listeners and properties of the marker with it.

```
function createMarker(point, cf, wh, html, i, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    draggable: true

  });
  var activeIcon, idleIcon;
  if (cf == "true") {
    idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png';
  } else if (wh == "true") {
    idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png';
  } else {
    idleIcon = 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png';
  }
  marker.setIcon(idleIcon);

  var elem = document.getElementById('a' + i);
  if (!!elem) {
    elem.onmouseover = function() {
      marker.setIcon('http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png');
    }
    elem.onmouseleave = function() {
      marker.setIcon(idleIcon);
    }
  }
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);

  });

  return marker;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
downloadUrl(<?= json_encode($url); ?>, function(data) {
  var xml = data.responseXML;
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
    var cf = markers[i].getAttribute("cf");
    var wh = markers[i].getAttribute("wh");
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
      parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
    createMarker(point, cf, wh, html, i, map);
  }
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5qk4zqz4/5/)